# How can I remove these game objects when loading a new scene?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, android-augmented-reality

I am trying to create an augmented reality quiz game. However, I have a problem when I finish one quiz. The Data controller which contains the questions isn't being destroyed properly after ending the quiz. It just adds up to the hierarchy.

By the way, I followed the Quiz Game tutorial from Unity.

```
public void EndRound () {


    isRoundActive = false;
    questionDisplay.SetActive (false);
    roundEndDisplay.SetActive (true);
    DestroyObject (FindObjectOfType<DataController> ());

}
```

How can I destroy the game object completely? So when I return to menu it will no longer add up and be part of the next quiz which will be selected. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
DestroyObject (FindObjectOfType<DataController> ());
```

will only destroy the component `DataController`. To destroy the game object tree you can write:

```
DestroyObject (FindObjectOfType<DataController>().gameObject);
```